# How to use JQuery in Laravel 5.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

**My Problem**

I wanted to use JQuery/Ajax to delete something from my database. But I could not get the function to fire on click of a button. Now I tried something easier, like hide a paragraph on click of a button but it does not work. I used different JQuery methods, but to no avail.

I also tried including JQuery in my master layout like so:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is some of my code:

```
 <!-- edit.blade.php-->

  <!-- HTML -->

  <button type="button" id="btnhide" class="btn">Hide</button>

  <p>Paragraph 1</p>

  <!-- JavaScript and JQuery -->
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(e){
      $("btnhide").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
        });
    });
  </script>
```

And here the whole blade file:

```
@extends('adminlte::page')

@section('title', '| Edit Employee')

@section('content_header')
@stop

@section('content')
  <div class='col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4'>

      <h1><i class='fa fa-user-plus'></i> Edit {{$employee->name}}</h1>
      <hr>

      {{ Form::model($employee, ['route' => ['employees.update', $employee->id], 'method' => 'PUT']) }}

      <div class="form-group">
          {{ Form::label('name', 'Name') }}
          {{ Form::text('name', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required')) }}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          {{ Form::label('email', 'Email') }}
          {{ Form::email('email', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required')) }}
      </div>

      <h5><b>Give Role</b></h5>

      <div class='form-group'>
          @foreach ($roles as $role)
              {{ Form::checkbox('roles[]',  $role->id, $employee->roles ) }}
              {{ Form::label($role->name, ucfirst($role->name)) }}<br>
          @endforeach
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          {{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }}<br>
          {{ Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => ' • • • • • • • • • •', 'required' => 'required')) }}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          {{ Form::label('password', 'Confirm Password') }}<br>
          {{ Form::password('password_confirmation', array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required')) }}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          {{ Form::label('qualifications', 'Qualifications') }}<br>
          {{ Form::select('qualifications', $employee_qualifications, null, ['size' => 5, 'class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'selectedqualification']) }}
          <button
             type="button"
             class="btn btn-default pull-right"
             data-toggle="modal"
             data-target="#qualificationModal"
             data-qualifications="{{ $qualifications }}"
             data-qualification_names="{{ $qualification_names }}">
             Add
          </button>
          <button type="button" id="removequali" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Remove</button>
          <button type="button" id="btnhide" class="btn">Hide</button>
          <br>
          <p> Test 1 </p>
          <br>
      </div>

      {{ Form::submit('Save', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
      {{ Form::close() }}

      @include('dispo.employees.add_qualification')
  </div>
@stop

@section('script')
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- JavaScript and JQuery -->
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(e){
      $("btnhide").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
        });
    });
  </script>

  <script>
    //Detaches the Qualification from the Employee via Ajax without refreshing the site
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".removequali").click(function(e){
        let qualificationid = $("#selectedqualification").val();
        $.ajax({
                   type: 'DELETE',
                   url: "{{URL::route('remove_qualification')}}",
                   dataType: 'json',
                   headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
                   data: {
                     'id': qualificationid,
                     'employeeid': "{{$employee->id}}",
                     '_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                   },

                   success: function (data) {
                        alert('success');
                   },
                   error: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                   }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>

@endsection
```

Comment: Can you tell me from View Page Souce or Inspect Element, what happens when you click on the link of this script? Is it loading?

Comment: Hey, how can I see if the script is working when I click on the button? It's only supposed to hide a paragraph

Comment: Just visit the page, right click and inspect element or view page source. You will find this `<script src="{{ asset('node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>`. Click on it and tell me what are you seeing is it empty or not?

Comment: Ah, okay, that script. It's not in my file anymore, I included a CDN instead. But it still won't work.

Comment: Please check your console. Are there any errors?

Comment: When I open the Chrome console by inspecting the button element and then click on it, no error is being displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Chrome console for errors, it should tell you what's wrong, few tips:

- Try enclosing your jquery calls to after the document is ready:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".btn-class").click(function(){
         $("p").hide();
     });
});
```

- If still doesn't work try using jquery cdn: https://code.jquery.com/

Comment: I enclosed the call and included a CDN in my master file as well as the blade file I'm currently working on, but that did not help. How can I use the Chrome console to find out what's wrong?

Comment: I updated the question to include the whole blade file, could you have another look?

Comment: Check your first script $("btnhide") doesn't exist, it should read $("#btnhide") missing the id selector:

Comment: Oh gosh, how embarrassing... Thank you, it works now!

Answer (score 1):

The Best thing you can do is use CDN to include jquery in your blade

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or download jquery and put it inside `public/js` folder and now you can include jquery in your balde template by using `asset()` helper function

```
asset('js/jquery.min.js')
```

Observe that there is no public because `asset()` helper by default loads files from public folder

Comment: I included the CDN in my master layout and in the blade file I'm working on, but I still can not get it to work.

Comment: No, I click on the button and nothing happens, no console errors.

Comment: can u please post the code so that it can be clear.!

Comment: I just updated my question, but what else should I post? I could post the whole blade file, if that would help...

Comment: I updated the question to include the whole blade file, could you have another look?

Comment: Are you using AdminLTE package?

Comment: Yes it is. I think there were a few things wrong. I included the CDN elsewere in the master layout and included a @yield('script') script as well, as you can see in the updated code. The final thing that was wrong was that $("btnhide") doesn't exist, it should read $("#btnhide").

Answer (score 0):

Node modules directory is not part of the assets
You should use the relative or the  absolute path

Or using a cdn if you can

Comment: Okay, thanks, but is JQuery not already included in Laravel 5.6 by default via the bootstrap.js file?

Comment: Well... Did you ran npm install ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Just did it again, but no change in behavior.

Comment: I updated the question to include the whole blade file, could you have another look?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Try this make sure you put the

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` before your `</head>`

Comment: I included the CDN in my master layout and in the blade file I'm working on, just to be sure, then I tried your code, but it still won't work...

Comment: @Dunrar do you have btn id? Make sure you have one.

Comment: I updated also my code try it and make sure your <input type="button" id="btn" value="Hide Paragraph/>

Comment: Yes, I have. The button html is this: <button type="button" id="btnhide" class="btn">Hide</button>. I changed your code to $("#btnhide").click(function(){...

Comment: @Dunrar then try this step if will work. Put my first line of src before your `</head>` then put my second script tag after your button. update my code to #btn to #btnhide

Comment: @Dunrar it was input type not button type.

Comment: The inclusion of the CDN happens before the </head> tag. The script is at the end of my blade file, but before the @stop of my @section('content'). I'm not sure I get what you mean by "it was input type not button type", could you please clarify?

Comment: <input type="button" id="btnhide" class="btn">Hide</button>

Comment: I updated the question to include the whole blade file, could you have another look?

Comment: No error, but nothing happens when I click on the button.

Comment: @Dunrar #btnhide change it to this in your script